# Regular expression to extract number with hyphen

Tags: python, regex

The text is like "1-2years. 3years. 10years."

I want get result `[(1,2),(3),(10)]`.

I use python.

I first tried `r"([0-9]?)[-]?([0-9])years"`. It works well except for the case of 10. I also tried `r"([0-9]?)[-]?([0-9]|10)years"` but the result is still `[(1,2),(3),(1,0)]`.

Comment: @Socowi I use python.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thanks for comment. I have added my attempt.

Comment: Please read [formatting help](/help/formatting). Using backticks to format your code makes it stand out and more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt `r"([0-9]?)[-]?([0-9])years"` doesn't work for the case of `10` because you ask it to match one (or zero) digit per group.

You also don't need the hyphen in brackets.

This should work: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/df7opd/1)

```
(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?years
```

Explanation:

- `(\d+)`: Capturing group for one or more digits
- `(?:      )`: Non-capturing group
- `-`     : hyphen
- `(\d+)`: Capturing group for one or more digits
- `(?:      )?`: Make the previous non-capturing group optional

In python:

```
import re

result = re.findall(r"(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?years", "1-2years. 3years. 10years.")

# Gives: [('1', '2'), ('3', ''), ('10', '')]
```

Each tuple in the list contains two elements: The number on the left side of the hyphen, and the number on the right side of the hyphen. Removing the blank elements is quite easy: you loop over each `item` in `result`, then you loop over each `match` in this `item` and only select it (and convert it to `int`) if it is not empty.

```
final_result = [tuple(int(match) for match in item if match) for item in result]

# gives: [(1, 2), (3,), (10,)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import re

st = '1-2years. 3years. 10years.'
result = [tuple(e for e in tup if e) 
          for tup in re.findall(r'(?:(\d+)-(\d+)|(\d+))years', st)]
# [('1', '2'), ('3',), ('10',)]
```

The regex will look for either one number, or two separated by a hyphen, immediately prior to the word `years`. If we give this to `re.findall()`, it will give us the output `[('1', '2', ''), ('', '', '3'), ('', '', '10')]`, so we also use a quick list comprehension to filter out the empty strings.

Alternately we could use `r'(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?years'` to basically the same effect, which is closer to what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern: `(?:(\d+)-)?(\d+)years`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/op7gNt/1)

**Code:**

```
import re

pattern = r"(?:(\d+)-)?(\d+)years"
text = "1-2years. 3years. 10years."
print([tuple(int(z) for z in x if z) for x in re.findall(pattern, text)])
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 2), (3,), (10,)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You only match a single digit as the character class `[0-9]` is not repeated.

Another option is to match the first digits with an optional part for - and digits.

Then you can split the matches on `-`

```
\b(\d+(?:-\d+)?)years\.
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 1** (which will be returned by re.findall)

  - `\d+(?:-\d+)?` Match 1+ digits and optionally match `-` and again 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `years\.` Match literally with the escaped `.`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8vczPE/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XxAIy8).

Example

```
pattern = r"\b(\d+(?:-\d+)?)years\."
s = "1-2years. 3years. 10years."

res = [tuple(v.split('-')) for v in re.findall(pattern, s)]
print(res)
```

*Output*

```
[('1', '2'), ('3',), ('10',)]
```

Or if a list of lists is also ok instead of tuples

```
res = [v.split('-') for v in re.findall(pattern, s)]
```

*Output*

```
[['1', '2'], ['3'], ['10']]
```